# SQL Pattern matching and replacing multiple values

Tags: sql, replace, pattern-matching, amazon-redshift

I have a string column with multiple words. I would like to use pattern searching and replacing multiple values if the condition is met.

Input table:

```
fruit
Red Apple, Bananas
apples, banana, orange
Strawberry, Strawberries
```

Output table:

```
fruit
Red Apple, Banana
Apple, Banana, orange
Strawberry, Strawberry
```

For example, I want to group `Apple`, `apple`, `apples` as `Apple`.

I thought of using the function REPLACE but with this function, it only allows me to search for 1 value instead of multiple values.

```
select replace(fruit, 'apples', 'Apple') as fruit 
from table
```

I also thought of this below approach, but it doesn't work either:

```
select case when fruit similar to '%(Apple|apple|apples)%' then 'Apple'
            when fruit similar to '%(Banana|banana|bananas)%' then 'Banana'
            when fruit similar to '%(Strawberry|strawberry|strawberries)%' then 'Strawberry'
       end as fruit 
from table
```

Could anyone please give me a suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: Storing multiple values in a string is problematic.  I would suggest you fix your data model.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *Amazon Redshift* but looking at the documentation I would have a go with the `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html

I would use the `p` for PCRE (since the Perl engine is complete and performant) and `i` for case-**i**nsensitive flags that you can pass as the last parameter.

I had a try with MySQL 8 which also has the `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function but with different parameters. It's almost the same. It seems that my machine had the `i` for case-insensitive activated by default so I didn't need to set the regular expression flags:

```sql
SELECT
`fruit` AS `before`,
REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
            REGEXP_REPLACE(`fruit`, 'apples?', 'Apple'),
            'bananas?',
            'Banana'
        ),
        'oranges?',
        'Orange'
    ),
    'strawberr(y|ies)',
    'Strawberry'
) AS `after`
FROM `fruits`
```

I didn't do any SQL update but just a select to show the before and after.

The second problem is your multiple entries of *straberry* and *straberries* in the same list of fruits. This could perhaps be corrected in a second step. Since the fruit will always be replaced by the singular version of the fruit with a first uppercase letter, we could capture the fruit and see if there's the same fruit later in the list. Example with the `m` **m**ultiline flag:

```sql
-- Using REGEXP_REPLACE() from MySQL 8 (not totally the same parameters).
SELECT
"Lemon, Lemon, Banana, Orange, Banana
Strawberry, Apple, Banana, Strawberry, Orange
Apple, Blueberry, Blueberry
Strawberry, Apple, Apple, Banana, Orange, Banana
Lemon, Apple, Lemon, Blueberry, Blueberry, Orange" AS `before`,
REGEXP_REPLACE(
    "Lemon, Lemon, Banana, Orange, Banana
Strawberry, Apple, Banana, Strawberry, Orange
Apple, Blueberry, Blueberry
Strawberry, Apple, Apple, Banana, Orange, Banana
Lemon, Apple, Lemon, Blueberry, Blueberry, Orange",
    '(^|,\\s*)([^\\s,]+)(.*?)\\s*,\\s*\\2',
    '$1$2$3',
    1,
    0,
    'm'
) AS `after`
```

The output is:

```text
Lemon, Banana, Orange
Strawberry, Apple, Banana, Orange
Apple, Blueberry
Strawberry, Apple, Banana, Orange
Lemon, Apple, Blueberry, Orange
```

[Play with it on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/K4cc5p/1). Just be carefull that the backslash `\` should be written twice in the SQL query since it has to be escaped.

But the idea of the regex to remove duplicates is to:

- search for a fruit with `[^\s,]+` which means any char which is not a space or a comma, at least once or several times.
- then I added the "*starting with or preceded by a comma*" in front of the fruit with `(^|,\s*)` in order to capture it and put it back in the replacement.
- the fruit is followed by something (which could be empty) that we want to capture, then a comma (with possible spaces around) and then followed by the same fruit. We use the regex backreference number 2 (which is the fruit): `(.*?)\s*,\s*\2`. The something after the fruit is searched in an ungreedy way so that we don't go to far ahead.

But in some cases the pattern will match a block already containing some duplicate fruits inside it: `Banana, Apple, Apple, Banana`. So the "*remove multiple occurences*" might have to be run more than once. Probably 2-3 times would be suffisient.